# Why I am I unable to mix matrix nodes multiple times with Animation Nodes?

Tags: node-editor, animation-nodes

I have some nodes setup that make use of the "mix Matrix" node with a specific factor input. It works great. Then I wanted to mix that mixed matrix with another combined matrix, but at that point it wont work anymore. So I guess my question is, is it possible to use multiple mix matrix nodes to mix "mix matrix" nodes? (sorry if it sounds convoluted)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, So, after some testing I realized that the output of a mix matrix node is actually a "result" (mind you im not a programmer) which gets inputed into an "object matrix output" node, so I simply connected an "object matrix input" immediately after the former and began a whole new sequence of Matrix calculations and it seems to work perfectly as I wanted. –